# Doctrine query builder not fetching 2M results

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a query which has to fetch more than 2M results. It's failing, I think because of a lack of memory.

Here's my query :

```
    $reponses = $qb ->select('r.id')
        ->from('PACESColleBundle:Reponse', 'r')
        ->join('r.user', 'u')
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('u.id', ':tutoreSalle'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('r.banque', ':banque'))
        ->setParameters(['banque' => 0, 'tutoreSalle' => $tutoreSalle])
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->update('PACESColleBundle:Reponse', 'r')
        ->set('r.banque', 1)
        ->set('r.archive', 1)
        ->where($qb->expr()->in('r.id', ':reponses'))
        ->setParameters(['reponses' => $reponses]);
    $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

The error stands in the first query. How can I make query builder fetch this amount of data ?

**EDIT :**

Changing this code to :

```
$db = $this->em->getConnection();
    $query = "UPDATE reponse AS rp
              SET rp.banque = 1, rp.archive = 1
              WHERE EXISTS (SELECT r.id
                            FROM (SELECT * FROM reponse) AS r
                            JOIN user u ON r.user = u.id 
                            JOIN tutore t ON u.id = t.id 
                            JOIN tutore_groupe tg ON tg.tutore_id = t.id 
                            WHERE tg.groupe_id = 1
                            AND r.id = rp.id)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Triggers this error :

```
General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"
```

Select statement is working well. It's when I try updating that it fails.

Comment: Batching would be a good way to processing that amount of data, check out: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

Comment: Problem is I use results from 1st query in the second so I can't detach results from the 1st query

Comment: Trying to process 2 million of anything in php is going to be challenging let alone using the Doctrine ORM.  You could replace your above code with a single sql statement using a nested select statement.

Comment: I agree with @Cerad, you could go for a nested select statement, in combination with the batching process I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I tried with a SQL statement but I have a new error. I edited my question. Can you take a look please ?

Comment: Have you added proper indexes for your columns ?